# Create third column that might be based on one of two columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data like this:  (many more columns not shown here)

```
    df<-structure(list(email = c("lbelcher@place.org", "bbelchery@place.org", 
"b.smith@place.org", "jsmith1@place.org"), employee_number = c(123456, 
654321, 664422, 321458)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I need to make a third column called "username".  Username is usually just everything before the @ in their email UNLESS there's a period or a number in that name, then it would be their employee number.

In other words, I'm hoping to get results like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `str_detect` on the substring of 'email' (before the `@`) to find for `.` or digits, then return the 'employee_number' or else remove the suffix part of 'email' with `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(username = case_when(str_detect(trimws(email,
      whitespace = "@.*"), "[.0-9]")
     ~ as.character(employee_number), TRUE ~ str_remove(email, "@.*")))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  email               employee_number username 
  <chr>                         <dbl> <chr>    
1 lbelcher@place.org           123456 lbelcher 
2 bbelchery@place.org          654321 bbelchery
3 b.smith@place.org            664422 664422   
4 jsmith1@place.org            321458 321458
```